# Issues with enabling CORS on the express/node server using react starter kit

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, cors, react-starter-kit

I've been trying to enable Cross-origin-resource-sharing using the links below:

[How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-node-js) 
http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html 
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

But i couldn't, 
I'm  using react-starter-kit and 
I think it should be something related to browser-sync. 
Is there's anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Did you try using this extension? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh

Comment: Thanks nabn... it's working now !!
But i need to know what's the problem with the mentioned ways